# Running two cameras at the same time (Pi Camera & USB camera)

Tags: raspbian, python, usb, camera

I would like for my project to have one camera (PiCamera) Streaming video. 
And another USB Camera (PS3 Camera) taking pictures when I execute this function:

```
def grabPicture(self):
      grab_cam = subprocess.Popen("sudo fswebcam --timestamp '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S (%Z)' -r 640x480 -d /dev/video0 -q /home/pi/pictures/%m-%d-%y-%H%M.jpg", shell=True)
      grab_cam.wait()
      todays_date = datetime.datetime.today()
      image_name = todays_date.strftime('%m-%d-%y-%H%M') + '.jpg'
      return image_name
```

The function above was working before I merge [this](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask) guys code with mine.

Now the above functions does not seems to respond. If I run the command:

```
sudo fswebcam --timestamp '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S (%Z)' -r 640x480 -d /dev/video0 -q /home/pi/pictures/%m-%d-%y-%H%M.jpg
```

is working fine. I think somehow the functions send the command to the PiCamera while PiCamera is busy with streaming. But Im not sure. Any ideas?